# Android Wifi EAP TLS using WifiEnterpriseConfig setClientKeyEntry

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

WifiEnterpriseConfig setClientKeyEntry method takes private key & certificate references.
I have a .p12 certificate stored in Android certificate store.
Can I use the KeyChain API (getCertificateChain, getPrivateKey) to get the private key and certificate reference and pass it to setClientKeyEntry?
Alternatively, if I have a .p12 certificate in String or byte array format, then do I need to store it in certificate store to be able to use it for Wifi EAP-TLS?

Assumptions: 
setClientKeyEntry method is required for programatically set EAP-TLS on the Android 4.3+ client.

Comment: From my testing, I observed that when I get the PrivateKey reference using KeyChain getPrivateKey method, and then use it in setClientKeyEntry then it throws exception- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key cannot be encoded. setClientKeyEntry method throws this exception if getEncoded method returns null for the PrivateKey object reference. It is not clear why getEncoded returns null.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
wc.SSID = "\"your_ssid\"";
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
wc.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(Eap.TLS);
wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

...

KeyStore pkcs12ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/your.p12")));
// alternatively you can read from any input stream, e.g. ByteArrayInputStream to read from String

pkcs12ks.load(in, "pasword".toCharArray());

Enumeration<String> aliases = pkcs12ks.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    Log.d(TAG, "Processing alias " + alias);

    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) pkcs12ks.getCertificate(alias);
    Log.d(TAG, cert.toString());

    PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) pkcs12ks.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
    Log.d(TAG, key.toString());

    wc.enterpriseConfig.setClientKeyEntry(key, cert);
    wc.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity("WiFi-1");
}

...

int netID = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netID, true);
```

Proper exception handling not shown.